# Autorização via token com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, autenticação, authorization

Vi que para setar o campo 'Authorization' do cabeçalho com Angular usa-se:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + token
```

ou

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Basic " + token
```

Qual a diferença entre o 'Bearer' e 'Basic'? E por que quando vou fazer a requisição via Postman não preciso concatenar o token com algum dos dois?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autenticação Basic e Digest são dedicados a autenticação usando um "login" e uma "senha".

Autenticação Bearer é dedicado a utilização de token para se autenticar.

A dúvida do Postman depende da forma que você está autenticando no caso do Basic não precisaria passar nenhum token mas no "Body" da requisição seria necessário informar o "login" e "senha".

Comment: No postman, seto apenas na aba de header o 'Authorization' : 'token'

Comment: Acho que não estamos nós entendendo, utilizo a aba "Headers" do Postman não a aba "Authorization".
E na aba "Headers" tenho que colocar a "key" Authorization e no "value" tenho que por "Bearer token" ( Bearer "espaço" token)

Comment: Exatamente isso que vc disse: Na aba "Headers", eu coloco na key 'Authorization' com o valor 'token' [sem bearer] e me retorna normal.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao servidor? O Bearer é definido pela especificação OAuth2 pode ser alguma configuração na aplicação que faz você conseguir acesso mesmo sem por o Bearer na frente do token.

Comment: Até tenho, mas acho que agora vc matou a questão. Porque provavelmente a aplicação não tenha sido desenvolvida usando o padrão OAuth.